# How do I run Chrome without any borders?

Tags: google-chrome

I am using google chrome to delivery web based content for a major international airport. This is currently done by running Chrome in Kiosk mode as it removes all borders, scroll and title bars. We have a video wall 5000 x 5000 pixels which I would like to use multiple google chrome instances to allow different content to be shown on different areas of the screen.

I have found some example code to allow multiple instances to be run at various locations and window sizes, but the issue is that app mode doesn’t create a borderless window. Any suggestions how I can achieve this would be welcome .

```
start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --app="https://site1.com/" --window-size="2560,1000" --window-position="0,0" --user-data-dir="C:/Profiles/1"
start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --app="https://site2.com/" --window-size="1280,1000" --window-position="0000,1000" --user-data-dir="C:Profiles/2"
start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --app="https://site3.com/" --window-size="1280,1000" --window-position="0000,1000" --user-data-dir="C:/Profiles/3
```

Comment: If the websites themselves are not too restrictive, you could consider one main page that devides the page into 4 frames using simple HTML `<frameset>`, and run that in kiosk mode

Comment: This isn't really possible, the other reason for individual instances is that access control and ability to change content is done on a url bases

Comment: You can change the url by editing the html file. Its a bit more difficult, true, but you just edit the html (can be done outside of the browser) then on the computer, hit refresh.